# Create button to change view in a list SP online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-framework

I have a Modern sharepoint online list with 2 views.
Is it possible to create 2 button to change the view "on the fly"?
either json or via ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar or is there an other way. I know I can create to links but that would reload the page and is to slow.

Thanks
Morten

Update:
Thanks [Denis](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/7868/denis-molodtsov) now i know React debug :)
It looks like the change view "button / menu" is a `customizedcommandbarbutton` see picture, but i cannot find what it does. Because it is rather easy to make command bar buttons.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert at SharePoint Framework, but I can guess that we can't create a menu custom action that somehow can change React's state from outside and cause the proper page re-render.

Theoretically, if it's somehow possible, maybe SPFx's [ListView command Set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-ecb-to-spfx-extensions) could do it. But I still doubt it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create a List View command set extension in SPFx and redirect the user to a different page when he clicks on the button, that should do a partial page reload by default, not a full page reload.